# Creating a BPMN diagram using ReactFlow in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, bpmn, react-flow

I'm working on a ReactJS application and I would like to create a BPMN diagram using ReactFlow. However, I'm unsure if ReactFlow supports the full set of BPMN elements and properties required for creating BPMN diagrams. Can I use ReactFlow to create a BPMN diagram, or do I need to use a different library like bpmn.io?

I've explored the ReactFlow documentation and examples, but I couldn't find specific information about BPMN support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.